# BroadcastReceiver is not started after device boot

Tags: android

After device reboot, I want to run my receiver so that the device can play audio when the device screen is turned on or turned off without setting them manually through the app.

MusicList.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.music_layout);
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockScreenService.class));

//other codes

});

//send chosen music
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if(lockIsChosen!=null) {
            //other codes
            try {
                Intent i = new Intent("my.action");
                i.putExtra("posLock", newPosition2).putExtra("songlistLock", mySongs).putExtra("lockSound", "lock");
                sendBroadcast(i);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Intent error");
            }
            finish();

        }
        if(unlockIsChosen!=null) {

            //other codes
            try {
                Intent i = new Intent("my.action.unlock");
                i.putExtra("posUnlock", newPosition3).putExtra("songlistUnlock", mySongs).putExtra("unlockSound", "unlock");
                sendBroadcast(i);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Intent error2");
            }

            finish();
        }
    }
});
```

This is what I wrote in my receiver

```
 public class LockScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 MediaPlayer mp;
 ArrayList<File> mySongs;
 ArrayList<File> mySongs2;
 Uri u;
 Uri u2;
 AudioManager am;

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         String action = intent.getAction();
         am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

         if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
             Intent service = new Intent(context, LockScreenService.class);
             context.startService(service);
          //I tried this just for testing, but no toast is shown after device reboot
             Toast.makeText(context, u2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }

         if(action.equals("my.action")) {
             Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
             mySongs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlistLock");
             int position = b.getInt("posLock", 0);

             u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
         }

         if(action.equals("my.action.unlock")) {
             Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
             mySongs2 = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlistUnlock");
             int position = b.getInt("posUnlock", 0);

             u2 = Uri.parse(mySongs2.get(position).toString());
         }

         if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) && am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
         {
             if(u2!=null) {
                 stopPlaying();
                 mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, u2);
                 mp.start();
                 Toast.makeText(context, u2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         }
         else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) && am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
         {
             if(u!=null) {
                 stopPlaying();
                 mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, u);
                 mp.start();
                 Toast.makeText(context, u.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }
         }

     }

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
}
```

And here's the Service class

```
public class LockScreenService extends Service {

BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onCreate() {

    //Start listening for the Screen On, Screen Off, and Boot completed actions
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
    //Set up a receiver to listen for the Intents in this Service
    receiver = new LockScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    registerReceiver( receiver, new IntentFilter( "my.action" ) );
    registerReceiver( receiver, new IntentFilter( "my.action.unlock" ) );

   //Toast is not shown after device reboot
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starting service now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

}
```

My manifest, which I believe there's nothing wrong with it

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_SERVICE"/>

    <service android:name=".LockScreenService" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".LockScreenReceiver">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="my.action" />
            <action android:name="my.action.unlock" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

What is it that I am doing wrong? Some says that I should do my stuff on service instead, but doing that will crash the app on boot. I've been stuck here for days. Please help.

Also, might be a relevant question: Do I need sharedpreferences for my app so that it is able to do what I want? The files fetched from device storage.

Here is the link to my source file, so that people can pinpoint what I do wrong
https://github.com/PiersonLeo94/SOUN-WAKE

Please take a look at the v1.1 version

Comment: 1). Change position of `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`, put it after `<application` tag with another permissions

2). Are you sure that your receiver doesn't start? Add debug line after `onReceive` method. For example: `Log.d("TAG", "Receiver start");`

Comment: This link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android

Comment: Please check whether 'onReceive' is called?.. Put a log here           '@Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         String action = intent.getAction();'

Comment: @DGN I have put a log in if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {} but it doesn't show it in my logcat.

Comment: @YuriyKolbasinskiy Yeah, I'm sure my receiver doesn't start. The log doesn't appear after device reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your manifest something like this.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dev.hb.testing">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver android:name=".LockScreenReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @PiersonLeo As per the above manifest configuration, I tested my application and it is working fine, I putted a log file to test and log is printing. Once try again.

Comment: Do you mind if I link you my github account so that you can take a look more clearly on what I do wrong?

Comment: @PiersonLeo no , you can link

Comment: Thank you! Here it is https://github.com/PiersonLeo94/SOUN-WAKE please take a look at the v1.1 version. It's the latest one

Comment: @PiersonLeo broadcast receiver is called when the device boots, I tested it.

Comment: Huh really? Does the song play?

Comment: @PiersonLeo I didn't checked that.But the log is coming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96408/discussion-between-pierson-leo-and-nigam-patro).